is there a code for zooming an output in babylonjs code
I actually wrote a babylon code for loading a babylon file using input tag.I got the output but i cant zoom my mesh using my mouse.I used arcrotatecamera.Code below.
I used arcrotaecamera itself . I can rotate the mesh but cant zoom
Pls help anybody
I tried using arcrotaecamera but it doesnt work
Pls help i tried many ways using chat gpt but it doesnt work ,My last option is you guys
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as BABYLON from '@babylonjs/core';

const BabylonViewer = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  let scene, camera, engine;

  useEffect(() => {
    engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvasRef.current, true);
    scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
    camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera('camera', 0, Math.PI / 4, 10, BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(0,1,0), scene);
    camera.attachControl(canvasRef.current, true);
    
    camera.radius = 10; // Increase the distance from the center of the scene
    const light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight('light', new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0), scene);

    engine.runRenderLoop(function () {
      scene.render();
    });

    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
      engine.resize();
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', function () {
        engine.resize();
      });
      scene.dispose();
      engine.dispose();
      // light._addToSceneRootNodes();
    };
  }, []);

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
      BABYLON.SceneLoader.Load('', reader.result, engine, function (loadedScene) {
        scene = loadedScene;
        camera = scene.activeCamera;
        camera.attachControl(canvasRef.current, true);

 

        camera.radius = 10; // Adjust the camera's radius here
        console.log(camera.radius);
      });
      
    };
   
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };



  

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
   
      <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{ width: '100%', height: 'calc(100vh - 40px)' }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BabylonViewer








